# Using archery with fighter maneuvers

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter, ranged-attack, combat-maneuver, battle-master

I was looking through the list of fighter battle master maneuvers, and I noticed that most of the maneuvers say 'a weapon attack' and not 'a melee weapon attack'. For example Disarming Attack only says 'weapon' while Lunging Attack specifies 'melee weapon'.

Does that means that if I am building an archer with a fighter, I can take the battle master option, and pick up maneuvers like Disarming Attack and happily use them with my bow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**

The vocabulary in the rules is such that when it means a close combat attack it refer to it as a *melee weapon attack* and a close combat weapon as a *melee weapon* and when it mean a ranged combat attack it refer to it as a *ranged weapon attack* and a ranged combat weapon as *ranged weapon*.

When it can be either, that is when it doesn't matter if it is a close combat or ranged combat attack or weapon the game rules just refer to it as *weapon attacks* or just say *weapon* without any qualifier.

So when a Battle Master maneuver just say a weapon attack you can happily use an bow to perform the necessary maneuver.

By my count only three maneuvers specifically required a melee weapon